# Angular - Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, random

i'm trying to put a random integer in my ng-src path, like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
      <img ng-src="{{randomPicture()}}" alt="">
</div>
```

And here's my basic function in my controller:

```
$scope.randomPicture = function(){
  var PATH = 'assets/images/';
  var image = Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);
  var ext = '.jpg';
  var randomPic = PATH + image + ext;

  return randomPic;
};
```

The images are displayed but in the console i have this error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

I found many questions on that here in stackoverflow but i still can't get rid of that error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: try this src="randomPicture()"

Comment: i tried this way but unfortunately unworking...

Comment: The following updated answer of floribon work perfectly and fixe error 10 $digest() issue in my case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your binding being random, it will be different every time Angular will execute the watcher of this binding.

However, Angular only stops a digest cycle when it reaches a stable state where all the watchers return the same value twice in a row, which never happens with yours.

In short, you cannot bind a random value, or anything that is always different, in an Angular binding. You should generate your picture once, and optionally re-randomize it based on some event.

```
$scope.randomPicture = generateRandomPicture();
```

And

```
<img ng-src="{{randomPicture}}">
```

**UPDATE:** And if you want to refresh the picture every 3 seconds for instance, you could add

```
// Generate a new random picture every 3 seconds
$interval(function() {
  $scope.randomPicture = generateRandomPicture();
}, 3000);
```

**Update 2:** Now that I understand better your problem, I would either suggest to keep everything as is but use `::` as shown below if using Angular 1.3 at least. This way you will have one random picture generated per user, but generated only once.

On an earlier verison of Angular or alternatively, you could generate a determinist image per user that would feel random. for instance in your HTML use:

```
<img ng-src="{{randomPicture($index)}}">
```

And in your controller

```
var rand1 = Math.round(Math.random()*10);
var rand2 = Math.round(Math.random()*10);

$scope.randomPicture = function(index) {
  var PATH = 'assets/images/';
  var image = (index+rand1*rand2)%13 + 1;
  var ext = '.jpg';
  var randomPic = PATH + image + ext;

  return randomPic;
};
```

---

Note that if you're using Angular 1.3+ and only want to generate the picture once, you can use *ont-time binding* using the `::` syntax (using the same code for `randomPicture`):

```
<img ng-src="{{::randomPicture()}}">
```

Comment: Thanks floribon for your help but with this solution:generateRandomPicture(), will generate only one time a new picture. It was my first solution to fixe the probleme.

Comment: Like i see some one else upvoting this answer, i just want to precise **that solution is not working...**

Comment: @adam the solution solves your problem: you simply cannot generate a random picture in this function. You should instead manually refresh the picture set in your scope when you want: after a timeout, a specific user action, etc. Maybe you could specify what exactly you were expecting to see? What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Thanks floribon, i don't precise my question your right. The image i'm talking about is in fact **Images** in a **ng-repeat** and what i want is to give to those images a unique image by adding a random integer in them path like in my example. So the $interval is not really the solution i need, i'm sorry for the confusion. i edited the question.

Comment: Oh I see, I've updated my answer another time to give you an idea of a solution. Do you want to avoid having two times the same picture or it's not a problem?

Comment: Thank you Floribon you are awesome, merci pour ton aide ;)

Comment: Glad you could solve your problem, please accept the answer if you're done with it et bonne journée :)